# Multiple secrets triggering conditions

Tags: hearthstone

How do multiple secrets interact in hearthstone?

Let's say I'm playing a hunter and I play both an explosive trap and a misdirection.  When I'm attacked by a minion which trap will trigger?

Comment: In that case I think it'd be whichever was most recently played.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Secrets are triggered in the order they are played.

In your example above, both will trigger.

However, if the attacking minion dies to the Explosive trap, the Misdirection is wasted. (For the record, I learned that the hard way).

Comment: But not every combination gets triggered. If you have Freezing trap + Misdirection, the first attacking minion will only get freezing trap, and your misdirection stays as a secret. But Misdirection + Freezing trap will first trigger the misdirection, select a random target, and then freezing trap the minion. Saw the latter occuring in one of TotalBiscuit's streams.